# Как извлечь JSON из HTML кода?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть вот такой HTML элемент:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">&#13;
    {&#13;
  "@context": "http://schema.org",&#13;
  "BaseSalary": {&#13;
    "Currency": "USD",&#13;
    "Value": {&#13;
      "UnitText": "YEAR",&#13;
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue"&#13;
    },&#13;
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount"&#13;
  },&#13;
  "DatePosted": "2020-05-15T05:04:20.193",&#13;
  "EducationRequirements": "",&#13;
  "EmploymentType": [&#13;
    "FULL_TIME"&#13;
  ],&#13;
  "ExperienceRequirements": "",&#13;
  "Identifier": "927323",&#13;
  "HiringOrganization": {&#13;
    "Name": "Staples Stores",&#13;
    "@type": "Organization"&#13;
  },&#13;
  "JobLocation": {&#13;
    "Address": {&#13;
      "AddressLocality": "Elgin",&#13;
      "AddressRegion": "IL",&#13;
      "AddressCountry": "US",&#13;
      "PostalCode": "60123",&#13;
      "@type": "PostalAddress"&#13;
    },&#13;
    "Geo": {&#13;
      "Latitude": 42.03891,&#13;
      "Longitude": -88.31189,&#13;
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates"&#13;
    },&#13;
    "@type": "Place"&#13;
  },&#13;
  "Title": "Xerox Certified iGen Operator",&#13;
  "@type": "JobPosting"&#13;
}&#13;
</script>&#13;
```

Надо текст, заключенный в тег `<script>`, извлечь в виде JSON, чтобы удобнее было с ним работать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно обработать html с помощью [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/):

```
# Сократил html из вопроса, чтобы не занимать лишнее место в ответе
text = '''
<script type="application/ld+json">&#13;
    {&#13;
  "@context": "http://s...content-available-to-author-only...a.org"&#13;
}&#13;
</script>&#13;
'''
 
import json
import html
import lxml.html

data = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
print(json.loads(
    html.unescape(
        data.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()')[0])))
```

Вывод:

```
{'@context': 'http://s...content-available-to-author-only...a.org'}
```

Comment: Парсить html как xml - это извращение, причём провальное.

Comment: И replace &#13; - тоже костыль.

Comment: @Qwertiy по поводу xml - соглашусь, в данном случае я бы тоже просто регулярками вытащил содержимое, но вы дали ответ быстрее) Попробую через HTMLParser переделать, хотя это наверное тоже overkill в данном случае. С replace - да, костыль, тут конечно лучше html.unescape использовать. Пока просто перенес код, который для коммента к вопросу на коленке написал.

Comment: В итоге переделал через lxml

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/AQm09c

```
import re
import html
import json

s= """j kj klajkldj lkdjslak jk
<script type="application/ld+json">&#13;
    {&#13;
  "@context": "..."&#13;
    }&#13;
</script>&#13;
ds ad sad ksalkd l;ask;l"""

print(
  json.loads(
    html.unescape(
      re.search(
        r"""<script\s+type\s*=\s*(["']?)application/ld\+json\1\s*>((?:(?!</script>)[\s\S])+)</script>""",
        s
      ).group(2)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Парсить html регулярками - это извращение, причём провальное. :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не провальное. Xml-парсер на html свалится, потому что html не является валидным xml'ем. А регулярка строку обработает. Ну и конкретно с тегом script содержимое регуляркой извлекается легко и правильно, хотя в своей версии я запретил ему иметь другие атрибуты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov полноценно парсить - да, извращение. Просто вытащить кусок текста - вполне нормальное решение, ИМХО.